# ruby add key to hash without value

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to add a key to hash without value? So I've created a hash(@j) and have a method:

```
def add(hash)
@j.merge!(hash) 
end
```

How do I make it possible to add keys, without value, example

```
@j.add('fish')
puts @j.entries
puts @j.keywords

=> {'fish' => nil}
=> fish
```

My current code allows me to add key and value like this:

```
 @j.add('fish' => 'animal')
```

But not if it were like above.... only the key

Comment: What would the point be? Do you want a set instead?

Comment: If you define the hash like my_hash = Hash.new { | k, v | k[ v ] = nil } ..when you query a undefined key, it will return nil :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can add a hash with nil for a value:

```
@j.add {:key => nil}
```

Or edit your add method:

```
def add(key_or_hash)
  hash = key_or_hash.is_a?(Hash) ? key_or_hash : {key_or_hash.to_sym => nil}
  @j.merge! hash
end
```

Comment: OP wants to `add keys, without value`

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is Ruby's Set class. From its description "Set implements a collection of unordered values with no duplicates. This is a hybrid of Array's intuitive inter-operation facilities and Hash's fast lookup".

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set a key to a nil value like so:

```
h = Hash.new

h["nil_key"] = nil

h.keys # => ["nil_key"]
```

in your example you could define it like this

```
def add(key, value = nil)
  h = { key => value } 
  @j.merge!(h)
end

@j = { :a_key => "a_value" }

@j.add("fish")

@j.keys # => [:a_key, "fish"]

@j.add("another_key", "another_value")

@j.keys # => [:a_key, "fish", "another_key"]

@j # => [ :a_key => "a_value", "fish" => nil, "another_key" => "another_value"]
```

just make sure you define #add in whatever class the @j instance variable is defined in.

Answer (score 0):

Using MRI Ruby 2.7: `hash.without(:this, :that, :the_other)`

Answer (score -1):

A hash is a mapping from keys to values. The idea of having a key without a value not only isn't possible, it doesn't even make sense.

Comment: It makes sense. Example: creating hash to add to CSV file. Calculation of each key might not return { key => nil } (DRY code). To make sure CSV will add hashes values to correct columns it is better to initialize keys in an advance.